# I want to call my function with string parameter

Tags: c++, string, function, function-calls

```
void GenerateDecryptedData("/home/merve/merve.enc", "/home/merve/merve.dec","dEneMe!1234");
```

I want to call my function like `dEneMe!1234`.

```
void GenerateDecryptedData(const char* pathToEncryptedFile, 
                        const char* pathToDeccryptedFile,
                        std::string Pwd);
```

But when I wrote the function prototype like this, I'm taking `string` has not been declared- error! How can I take my password in string type?

Comment: add #include <string>

Comment: I added #include <cstring> . Is this not enough? @0d0a

Comment: No <cstring> is a different library (inherited from C)

Comment: By the way it's better to change the first two parameters to `std::string` too

Comment: possible duplicate of [Difference between <cstring> and <string>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12824595/difference-between-cstring-and-string)

Comment: But those are not string values, those are just file paths @NetVipeC

Comment: And what benefice do you gain from `char*` and not from `std::string` for file paths?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the string header at the top of your source file: **`#include <string>`**. I'd consider Googling error messages more often. :)

string header - http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/
cstring header - http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with:

```
void GenerateDecryptedData(const char* pathToEncryptedFile, const char* pathToDeccryptedFile, const char* Pwd);
```

Comment: I tried this one too but then it's saying something wrong with "dEneMe!1234"
Why then I call this way?

Comment: If you tried that, why didn't you say so? Post that you've tried it, and what happened when you did.

Comment: I know--welcome to Stack Overflow! Add these as edits to your question, not comments here. Also, try Collin's answer.

Comment: Oh my God! The answer writing the whole time. It's a function call not  a function decleration. I'm very sorry.